# How to ensure my app deployed on google app engine is event driven?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a google cloud function that gets triggered whenever I upload a new file (1 file every 24 hours) to a bucket.

The function then generate an object into another bucket. There is an overwrite of the object every time the function is triggered.

I also have an app deployed on Google App Engine that picks up data from the object to generate a web app.

My question is how do i get the App Engine to run only when there is an overwrite of the object.(Like does trigger option (cloud storage) exist for Google App Engine). (Event driven)

I also don't think using a cron job to do this is ideal since like I said a new file gets uploaded just once in 24 hours and I can't predict the period of the day it gets uploaded.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to [sink the Cloud Storage event into PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications). Then, you have the messages in PubSUb, and you have to create a push subscription to invoke your App Engine to process what you want with your event.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am just going to do that and revert if I encounter any issue